# BIDS 2008 SSRS Projects show Exclaimation Marks

Tags: reporting-services, tfs, bids, rdl

I have created a solution that contains several SSRS report projects.  Each project contains definitions for a handful of report files (.RDLs).  They are broken into multiple project because each project coorelates with a different deployment directory.

I checked the solution into TFS 2010.  I am preparing documentation for the developers on how to get the solution, so I backed up it and removed it from my workstation.  I did a simple “Open from source control” commands within BIDS 2008.  The project was pulled from source control and ended up in exactly the same location with exactly the same folder structure and filenames.  However, each RDL in every project has a lock with an exclamation mark in a yellow icon next to it.  I am looking for the reason this icon is displayed, but simply don’t see it.

I have researched the problem on the internet, but most everything out there refers to moving files between projects or missing dependency references.  I have neither of those issues at play here.

Can anyone suggest what the cause of the warning icons are, or a method to diagnose?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same exact issue.  All I had to do was to close the BIDS exe and than rerun it.  After opening the solution again from the "recent Projects" link the projects open and the exclaimation marks are gone!  Hopefully you've also figured this out by now.

Answer (score 1):

First I apologize for the amount of xml code you will see to explain what's going on.

We have the same problem here.  What I've found, is for whatever reason, when a new report file is added to the project; regardless of the name, it places it at the end of the list in the solution explorer.

In addition it places this  as the last child in the  list.  Upon committing to TFS and pulling it back down the xml nodes are still the same way, but in your solution explorer the files appear in the correct alpha orders.  However, since the project xml and solution explorer are out of sync, you get the exclamation marks.

The solution I've found in to unload the project file go in and edit the xml placing the  element in the correct alpha order.

Example

```
<Reports>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>AccountGroupListing.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>AccountGroupListing.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>ApprovalRouteListing.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>ApprovalRouteListing.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>BalanceSheetWCodesReport.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>BalanceSheetWCodesReport.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>BalanceSheetWOCodesReport.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>BalanceSheetWOCodesReport.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>BankAccountListing.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>BankAccountListing.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>BankReconDetail.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>BankReconDetail.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>BankReconSummary.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>BankReconSummary.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>BasicBudgetProof.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>BasicBudgetProof.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>BillsToBeApproved.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>BillsToBeApproved.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>ChartOfAccountsListing.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>ChartOfAccountsListing.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>DoubleEntryGuideListing.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>DoubleEntryGuideListing.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>DoubleEntryPaymentProcessing.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>DoubleEntryPaymentProcessing.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>DoubleEntryReport.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>DoubleEntryReport.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>DoubleEntryReportDetail.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>DoubleEntryReportDetail.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>InvoiceForm.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>InvoiceForm.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>InvoiceFormSelfSealer.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>InvoiceFormSelfSealer.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>PaymentHistory.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>PaymentHistory.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>PaymentRegisterDetailReport.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>PaymentRegisterDetailReport.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>PaymentRegisterSummaryReport.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>PaymentRegisterSummaryReport.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>POByAccountCode.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>POByAccountCode.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>POPaperlessDistibutions.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>POPaperlessDistibutions.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>PORequiresPayment.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>PORequiresPayment.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>ProrationListing.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>ProrationListing.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>PurchaseOrderForm.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>PurchaseOrderForm.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>PurchaseOrderFormLineItems.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>PurchaseOrderFormLineItems.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>ReceivablesReport.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>ReceivablesReport.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>RequisitionApprovalAudit.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>RequisitionApprovalAudit.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>RequisitionForm.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>RequisitionForm.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>RequisitionProof.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>RequisitionProof.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>RevenuesReport.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>RevenuesReport.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>UnapprovedRequisitions.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>UnapprovedRequisitions.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>VoidPayments.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>VoidPayments.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>LoriTest.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>LoriTest.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
```

Notice how the LoriTest.rdl is coming after the VoidPayments.rdl file.  And if you look at my image how the icon has the exclamation mark.

[image: Solution Explorer]

My coworker added this file, committed the changes and I pulled them down.  The file appears in the correct order in the solution explorer, but not in the actual project xml.  If I close BIDS and re-open the mark goes away, but the project file is still messed up, UNTIL I add a new file.  Now my file is placed at the end and the loritest.rdl gets moved up in the list into the correct alpha order.

See my second image.

[image: Solution Explorer 2]

Now look at the project file code

```
<Reports>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>AccountGroupListing.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>AccountGroupListing.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>ApprovalRouteListing.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>ApprovalRouteListing.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>BalanceSheetWCodesReport.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>BalanceSheetWCodesReport.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>BalanceSheetWOCodesReport.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>BalanceSheetWOCodesReport.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>BankAccountListing.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>BankAccountListing.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>BankReconDetail.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>BankReconDetail.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>BankReconSummary.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>BankReconSummary.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>BasicBudgetProof.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>BasicBudgetProof.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>BillsToBeApproved.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>BillsToBeApproved.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>ChartOfAccountsListing.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>ChartOfAccountsListing.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>DoubleEntryGuideListing.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>DoubleEntryGuideListing.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>DoubleEntryPaymentProcessing.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>DoubleEntryPaymentProcessing.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>DoubleEntryReport.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>DoubleEntryReport.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>DoubleEntryReportDetail.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>DoubleEntryReportDetail.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>InvoiceForm.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>InvoiceForm.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>InvoiceFormSelfSealer.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>InvoiceFormSelfSealer.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>LoriTest.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>LoriTest.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>PaymentHistory.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>PaymentHistory.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>PaymentRegisterDetailReport.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>PaymentRegisterDetailReport.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>PaymentRegisterSummaryReport.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>PaymentRegisterSummaryReport.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>POByAccountCode.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>POByAccountCode.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>POPaperlessDistibutions.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>POPaperlessDistibutions.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>PORequiresPayment.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>PORequiresPayment.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>ProrationListing.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>ProrationListing.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>PurchaseOrderForm.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>PurchaseOrderForm.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>PurchaseOrderFormLineItems.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>PurchaseOrderFormLineItems.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>ReceivablesReport.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>ReceivablesReport.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>RequisitionApprovalAudit.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>RequisitionApprovalAudit.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>RequisitionForm.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>RequisitionForm.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>RequisitionProof.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>RequisitionProof.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>RevenuesReport.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>RevenuesReport.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>UnapprovedRequisitions.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>UnapprovedRequisitions.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>VoidPayments.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>VoidPayments.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem>
  <Name>DerekTest.rdl</Name>
  <FullPath>DerekTest.rdl</FullPath>
</ProjectItem>
```

What I've found that you need to do is after YOU, meaning the person adding a new file, needs to do is after they add the new report file, unload the project file and edit the project file directly to place the file in the correct order.  You don't have to absolutely do this, but if you don't do a get before a commit you can run into problem when multiple people are working on adding reports, because they become override in the project file, yet they, the reports, exist in the source control.

Hopefully this helps explain what is going on.  I've yet to really find a fix all solution for this.  My thought is to create a script or a VS plugin to fix the ordering issue.  You'd think Microsoft would have noticed this bug in VS/BIDS and have a hotfix for it, but again I've yet to find it.